# Google Sheets combine Columns unless Column value is that of other columns value

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a list of columns that contain city names:

```
E1 = New York
F1 = SF
G1 = Toronto
H1 = Seattle
```

Now lets assume `A1` is `Toronto` - I now want to combine `E:H` except for `A1`.

The usual formula would be `=E1&","&" "&F1&","&" "&G1","&" "&H1`. However, since `A1` is `Toronto`, `G1` shouldn't be added.

How do I pull this off?

Answer (score 1):

You could use formula:

```
=JOIN(", ",FILTER(E1:H1;E1:H1<>A1))
```

it uses filter to exclude A1 value (now I know filter works for both: vertical and horizontal ranges!).

And join is used to combine line into one string, and devide all values with comma and space.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with If condition to combine data from E:H. Eg: Below will merge if value is not same as A1.

```
=IF(E1=$A$1,"",E1&", ")&IF(F1=$A$1,"",F1&", ")&IF(G1=$A$1,"",G1&", ")&IF(H1=$A$1,"",H1&", ")
```

Please refer link [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c2J06YZXflKA9RYEI0OqcAa3sVBIiNLDdNcaD4LYWHc/edit#gid=0).